# List all rails routes with http method associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I use this method to list all routes of my rails application:

```
def routes
  Rails.application.routes.routes.collect do |r|
    { path: r.path.spec.to_s }
  end
end
```

My result is:

```
[
  { :path => '/my/path/' },
  { :path => '/my/path2/' },
  ...
]
```

I want to obtain also the http method used for that route. How to do it?
Exploring class documentation I couldn't find it.

The expected result is:

```
[
  { :path => '/my/path/', :method => :get },
  { :path => '/my/path2/', :method => :post },
  ...
]
```

There is a way to obtain the http method associated to a route? (or a list of methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActionDispatch::Journey::Route](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActionDispatch/Journey/Route) has a [verb](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActionDispatch/Journey/Route#verb-instance_method) method which returns a [RegExp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html):

You could try this:

```
def routes
    Rails.application.routes.routes.collect do |r|
        { path: r.path.spec.to_s, :verb => r.verb.source[/[a-z]+/i].to_sym }
    end
end
```

Comment: Well. You already gave the answer. Better to comment `:verb => r.verb.source[/[a-z]+/i].to_sym`.

Comment: see `Rails.application.routes.routes.map{ |r| r.verb.source }
 # => ["", "^GET$", "^GET$", "^GET$", "^POST$", "^DELETE$", "^POST$",..]`